# How does "bluebird weather" get its name?

Tags: etymology, history

In Maryland and Virginia, **bluebird weather** is a brief period of warm weather in autumn.

https://www.waywordradio.org/bluebird-weather/

How does “bluebird weather” get its name? This article explains the spiritual meaning of bluebird. I don’t see how it is related to “bluebird weather”.

> Bluebirds are known as “Spirit Animals,” who carry messages from the
>   spirit world. The bluebird meaning is happiness and pleasure. Any
>   positive sentiment is always attached to the bluebird; whether it is
>   happiness, pleasure, prosperity, or good health.
>
> https://www.guardian-angel-reading.com/blog-of-the-angels/bluebird-meaning/?media=BLOG&campaign=bluebird-meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It apparently derives its figurative meaning from a poem as explained below:

> Figurative use in [bluebird](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bluebird)  of happiness is from 1909 play romance "l'Oiseau bleu," literally "The Blue Bird," by Belgian dramatist and poet Maurice Maeterlinck (1862-1949).

(Etymonline)

Its usage is not confined to weather as suggested by a [BusinessToday](https://m.businesstoday.in/story/new-words-in-business/1/13969.html)

> Bluebird has been increasingly used in corporate circles in the past few years.

Usage:

> The company's game plan to widen its customer base ensured some bluebird sales.

Comment: Does it just mean "good"?

Comment: I have the same question. Bluebird: Denoting or relating to a period of time characterized by sunny, cloudless weather, typically after a night of snowfall.  (Lexico).  Does it just mean "good" and "happy"?

Comment: @luxury20041985 - it is clearly an extension of its literal meaning, but figuratively it may refer to something good, positive as in the case of business.